# Scapy - Removing Dot1q (801.2 Q) from a pcap

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to send `TCP` traffic to a device using a python script.
My script reads a particular `pcap` for processing packets.
In my `packet capture  file` there is Dot1Q VLAN tagging and I would like to remove it using `scapy` in my script.

Output contains the following :

> Ether / Dot1Q / IP / TCP >: port  > : port

Please tell how I can remove the vlan tagging in my script using scapy.

Answer (score 1):

You should walk through all layers and find `Ether`. Then set its payload to the payload of 802.1q layer. The code looks like (it's not the exact code by just the sketch):

```
while not isinstance(layer, NoPayload):
    if (type(layer) is Ether):
        payload_inside_dot1q = layer.payload.payload
        layer.add_payload(payload_inside_dot1q)
        layer.type = 0x0800  # IPv4
    layer = layer.payload
```

You probably should also correct `layer.chksum` for Ether layer.

UPD: You can also remove 802.1q layer tcprewrite (https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcprewrite) when preparing pcap file:

```
tcprewrite --enet-vlan=del --infile=input.cap --outfile=output.cap
```

Comment: Thanks but I am completely new to scapy and need more clarification.FYI ,the args in my code are passed from a file .But I would like to know from where I can extract the variable 'layer' .
    
    from scapy.all import *
    from scapy.error import Scapy_Exception
    pkts=rdpcap(sys.argv[9])
    for pkt in pkts:
        if pkt[IP].dst == 'x.x.x.x':
           pkt[Ether].src= sys.argv[1]
           pkt[Ether].dst= sys.argv[2]
           pkt[IP].src= sys.argv[5]
           pkt[IP].dst= sys.argv[6]
           del pkt[IP].chksum
          sendp(pkt, verbose=0,iface= sys.argv[7])

Comment: I missed it in my snippet. Import is: from scapy.all import NoPayload, Ether.
layer variable should be set to the 1st layer for every packet: for pkt in pkts: layer = pkt.firstlayer()